# how to add two functionality on single click of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, css

i want to add two functionality to the one checkbox one for backend and one for frontend 1st is after clicking it shows that option on front-end and 2nd is after clicking it shows the table to enter data in backend

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please add more description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You mean you want to run 2 functions with 1 single button click?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to click two times on the same element, which will result in 2 differents pre-defined actions.

To do so, you need to call a function that will keep track of the number of times you clicked it.

```js
let clickCount = 0;

function onClick(e) {
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount === 1) {
        showOptionsOnFrontEnd(); //Your first action
    }
    else if (clickCount === 2) {
        showTable(); //Your second action
    }
}
```

Is that what you need?

A more detailed question could lead to more precise answers though.